# N-1 polynomial fit using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, polynomial-math

Doing a question and one part involves using numpy to fit a set of PES data to an N-1 polynomial of `E(R) = summation(Ck*(r - rg))` , where `rg` is a guess for the minimum point of the PES. I have all data from the PES imported and just need to figure out how to fit it to a polynomial

```
import numpy as np

with open("hf_ccsdt_cbs45.txt", "r") as File:
    inputData = File.read()

    lines = inputData.splitlines()

    captions = lines[0]

    distances = []
    energies = []

    for line in lines[1:]:

        if line.strip() == "": 
            continue

        parts = line.split()
        distances.append(float(parts[0]))
        energies.append(float(parts[1]))

import pylab as pl

pl.plot(distances, energies)
pl.xlabel('Interatmoic Distance R (Bohr)')
pl.ylabel('Energy E[R]/(HARTREE')
pl.show()

r_guess = distances[np.argmin(energies)]
```

Comment: One of the tings I love about the `numpy` tag is running into people from wildly different corners of science and technology all trying to do more or less the same things.  But sometimes the terminology makes it a bit difficult to know which of those things are being asked.  Can you try to untangle your acronyms and make the question a bit more comprehensible to someone who is not an expert in . . . I'm going to guess Nuclear Physics, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe try reading [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Ah, electronic structure calculations... the indentation of your code is messed up, and your fitting function doesn't seem to have any exponents! For polynomial fitting try `np.polyfit(distances, energies, N-1)`.